# python tuple in sql

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using tuple to set params in sql query but it converts str params to int. I need the params keep being a string.

From a function I create a query using .sql file.
My .sql file is something like that:

```
update table t
set t.status = %s
where t.id in (%s)
```

My function to create a query from file is:

```
def create_query(where=[]):
   path = f'./file.sql'
   with open(path, 'r') as file:
      query = file.readlines()
      return ' '.join(query)

   return None
```

I call my function from this way passing the parameters:

```
status = 'CREATED'
ids = ('123', '1324', '124512')

params = list([ status, ids ])
query = create_query() % tuple(params)
```

I get a query like this:

> update table t set t.status = CREATED  where t.id in (22457, 22458,
> 22459)

I would like to do the interpolation keeping the quotations marks.
So, the query should look like this:

> update table t set t.status = 'CREATED'  where t.id in (22457, 22458,
> 22459)

If I do this:

```
status = ('CREATED',)
ids = ('123', '1324', '124512')

params = list([ status, ids ])
query = create_query() % params
```

I get this:

> update table t set t.status = ('CREATED',)  where t.id in (22457, 22458, 22459)
> And it doesn't work for errors in my sql (comma in status).

**I'm using sqlalchemy**

I solved the problem modifying my .sql file adding single quote.

```
update table t
set t.status = '%s'
where t.id in (%s)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach here is to generate the `IN` clause with the correct number of placeholders based on the number of values.  For example:

```py
status = ('CREATED',)
ids = ('123', '1324', '124512',)
params = status + ids
where = '(%s' + ',%s'*(len(ids) - 1) + ')'
sql = 'update some_table t set t.status = %s where t.id in ' + where
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: I tried but I get this: update some_table t set t.status = CREATED where t.id in (123,1324,124512) where CREATED must be 'CREATED' with quotations marks
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` in the query so the parameters are replaced by sql and you don't have to worry about the quotes:

```
status = ('CREATED',)
ids = (123, 1324, 124512, 33333, 44444)
params = status + ids
sql = f'update t set status = ? where id in (?{", ?"*(len(ids)-1)});'
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

asuming `id` is `INT`

Comment: I tried but I get this: update some_table t set t.status = CREATED where t.id in (123,1324,124512) where CREATED must be 'CREATED' with quotations marks
thank you

Comment: I'm using sqlalchemy